# Creating HTTPS secure soap web service in asp.net that requires certificate to be invoked

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, soap

I am trying to create a soap web service that will have one web method which takes name as input and will return "hello "+name over HTTPS and will require some certificate to be added in order to be invoked.

I have created a self signed certificate in IIS and have added HTTPS binding with certificate. I have added my application under default web site and have enabled SSL on it.

In the visual studio, I have created WCF service application, enabled SSL on it. Added asmx file that contains only one method in class. Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace POCSoap
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "https://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(string name)
        {
            return "Hello "+name;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added binding and service declaration to web.config as well.

```
<services>
          <service name="POCSoap.Service1">
              <endpoint address=""
                        binding="basicHttpBinding"
                        bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                        contract="POCSoap.IService1"/>

              <endpoint address="mex"
                        binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
      </services>
      <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
                  <security mode="Transport">
                      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                  </security>
              </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
```

Still, Call through http is working and call through https is not working. What is missing here.

Comment: define "not working". Add any error message you get.

Comment: @Gusman Error: read ECONNRESET

Answer (score 0):

WCF service is a web service other than XML web service(ASMX). They are different web service specification.
In order to make WCF service work over HTTPS, we should define a service endpoint with transport security like you do and the service contract, service implementation. Moreover, An Https binding in IIS site binding is required for working over HTTPS.
**IService.cs**

```
namespace POCSoap
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        string HelloWorld(string name);
        }}
```

**Service1.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string HelloWorld(string name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name;
        }
```

However, the invocation is completed by a client-side proxy instead of directly sending an HTTP request.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client#add-service-reference-in-visual-studio
As for the ASMX service, we need to call it with a client proxy either. therefore, I would like to know why the call through https is not working when you have already added an https binding in IIS.
To create a Rest API in WCF, which can directly called with a simple Http request(http verb,request body), we need to change the way to create the WCF service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="rest"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

At last, what do you mean that requiring certificate to be invoked? you want to authenticate client with a certificate, is that correct? This depends on which web service you use, WCF service or Xml web service.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.